# Iterating with Handlebars #each over an array of strings in Meteor

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I have an array of strings of userId's and iterate through in a template with {{#each}}. However, #each seems to want an object and converts each string into and object like so:

```
String {0: "T", 1: "e", 2: "2", 3: "s", 4: "y", 5: "D", 6: "g", 7: "G", 8: "d", 9: "K", 10: "e", 11: "i", 12: "i", 13: "Q", 14: "S", 15: "i", 16: "W"}
```

Pretty annoying. Any ideas how to avoid this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just iterate through the user objects?

Comment: The problem is that JavaScript wants `this` to be an object.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
this.toString()
```

Might be more robust than `String(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and

```
this.toString()
```

fixed the problem, but as someone new to Meteor I am curious why this is happening and if this is an acceptable solution for the problem.

**Data**

```
client {
    exampleProerty: value,
    projectManagers: [
        userId,
        userId 
    ],
    examleTwo: value
}
```

**Template**

```
{{#each projectManagers}}
    {{> userTemplate}}
{{/each}}
```

**Template Helper**

```
Template.userTemplate.helpers({

user: function() {
    var id = this.toString();
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: id});
    return user;
}

});
```

Otherwise, hoped this helped someone else.

Comment: This is not a good answer! You're querying the database from your view, adding an additional dependency to your storage. Try to get all information before start rendering.

Answer (score 1):

For example, to display a list of items from an array:

```js
// input to template
const shopping_list = [
  'Apples',
  'Oranges',
  'Bread',
  'Peanut Butter'
];

// template.hbs
<ul>
  {{#each shopping_list}}
    <li>{{this}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Expected result:

- Apples
- Oranges
- Bread
- Peanut Butter

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
String(this)
```

pretty inelegant having to do that though...

Comment: Also, keep in mind that with this constructor you don't get "real" strings, but string objects. They behave **mostly** the same, but some common assumptions are broken. For example, `typeof "asdf" === "string"`, but `typeof String("asdf") === "object"`.

Comment: I've just checked the above statement and it appears that `typeof String("asdf") === "string"` in current Firefox. So that problem is browser dependent - even funnier to debug.